# string array remains blank after calling it

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call, var

When call this from the file `hfunc.js` the var `vid` appears to be blank in my DOM. (I've checked it with `alert(vid.length)`):

```
var vid = [];
$(document).ready(function wfiller() {
    for (var n = 0; n < 1; n++)
        vid[0] = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0xpAqxH2Kzw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
});
```

on `head` tag:

```
<script>src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"</script>
<script>src="hfunc.js"</script>
```

I want to show the iframe using `document.write(vid[0])`.

p.s: I'm pretty sure I've screwed up `$(document).ready` somehow.

Comment: Your document.ready function is correct.

Comment: Your `script` tags are incorrectly formatted too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function wfiller() {
        for (var n = 0; n < 1; n++)
            vid[0] = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0xpAqxH2Kzw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    }
    wfiller();
    document.write(vid[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how jQuery document.ready function should be described:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{  
    for (var n=0; n<1; n++)
        vid[0] = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0xpAqxH2Kzw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
});
```

Look at this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sydgv351/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your document.ready is fine but script tags are wrong, instead of

```
<script>src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"</script>
<script>src="hfunc.js"</script>
```

Try

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="hfunc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: In HTML5, [`text/javascript`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type) is the default [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) type, so you don't need to include it.